# A counterexample involving $L^1$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Most people who have taken Real Analysis know of the counterexample which disproves the implication that $f_k, f \in L^1(m)$, $f_k \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere implies $\int |f_k - f| \rightarrow 0$; namely, that $f_k = \chi_{[k,k+1]}$.

I would like to find a counterexample to the same implication as written above, with the added hypothesis that $\int |f_k| \leq \int |f|$ for all $k$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Fatou's lemma, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int|f_n|\mathrm d\mu=\int|f|\mathrm d\mu$. Define $g_n:=|f_n-f|-|f|+|f_n|$. We have $g_n\geqslant 0$, $g_n\to 0$ almost everywhere. We then conclude by Fatou's lemma.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thank you.